# Running queries on tables with more than 1million rows in

Tags: php, mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I am indexing all the columns that I use in my Where / Order by, is there anything else I can do to speed the queries up?

The queries are very simple, like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
  FROM TABLE 
 WHERE user = id 
   AND other_column = 'something'`
```

I am using PHP 5, MySQL client version: 4.1.22 and my tables are MyISAM.

Comment: Are you working with all the data at once?

Comment: try count(1) - some argue there is no diffrence -worth a shot - Also is the id numeric? can the other column be diffrent type to text eg enum or number

Comment: @Rob: `COUNT(*)` will use an index already.

Comment: @webbiedave Sorry forgive me - Just looked it up count(1) is no diffrent to count(*)

Comment: @webnoob, what MySQL *server* version are you using?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Talk to your DBA. Run your local equivalent of `showplan`. For a query like your sample, I would suspect that a covering index on the columns `id` and `other_column` would greatly speed up performance. (I assume `user` is a variable or niladic function).

A good general rule is the columns in the index should go from left to right in descending order of variance. That is, that column varying most rapidly in value should be the first column in the index and that column varying least rapidly should be the last column in the index. Seems counter intuitive, but there you go. The query optimizer likes narrowing things down as fast as possible.

Answer (score 1):

If all your queries include a user id then you can start with the assumption that userid should be included in each of your indexes, probably as the first field. (Can we assume that the user id is highly selective? i.e. that any single user doesn't have more than several thousand records?)

So your indexes might be:

```
user + otherfield1
user + otherfield2
etc.
```

If your user id is *really* selective, like several dozen records, then just the index on that field should be pretty effective (sub-second return).

What's nice about a "user + otherfield" index is that mysql doesn't even need to look at the data records. The index has a pointer for each record and it can just count the pointers.

Comment: Nope, works with myisam indexes too, as long as it can find out everything it needs without looking at the record to see more fields than what are in the index.